# MouseArea in qml(onEntered, onExited, onReleased)

Tags: qml

I have one button. I want to change the states of button e.g:

Default image is `black`.
`onEntered` i want image as `blue`, `onExited` i want image as `black`(equal to default state), and `onReleased` i want image as `blue`(equal to onEntered state).

> Note:
>   `onRelease` should be active inside the button and outside the button `onRelease` shouldn't work.

How this can be achieved?

Mouse area looks like this:

```
MouseArea
{
    anchors.fill: firstImage(parent)
    onEntered:
    {
        firstImage.source = "blue.img"
    }
    onExited:
    {
        firstImage.source = "black.img"
    }
    onReleased:
    {
        firstImage.source = "blue.img"
    }
}
```

Problem i am facing is:
`onRelease` is active outside the button.
I want `onRelease` to be active when press is released inside the button.

Comment: What is `anchors.fill: firstImage(parent)` supposed to mean? If you are trying to get the parent of `firstImage` you should do `firstImage.parent`

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the fact that you can give every object in qml an extra custom property.

I came up with the following, which seems to be what you ask, however, I see a flaw, because when you are 'entered' and press, the button will go to entered state, so there is not difference in the 'released' state, and after leaving the MouseArea it will again go to 'exited' state.

*Note, I did not copy the firstImage.source stuff, but you can easily tailor this example to your situation*

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4

Button {

    hoverEnabled: true

    property bool touched : false

    onHoveredChanged: touched = hovered
    onReleased: touched = true

    text: touched ? "touched" : "not touched"
}
```

*The `hoverEnabled` needs to be set*

Comment: What u did is correct. I tried the same using images, it worked. But i want one more feature i.e. onclicked inside mouse area, i want to show the onEntered and onExited state too. Please try this code (using images).

Comment: Window
{ id: mainwindow
    property string img_src: "abc.png"
    property string img;
    Button
    {width: 100; height: 50; hoverEnabled: false
        onHoveredChanged: img_src = hovered
        onReleased: img_src = "HDX_Caps_Enter_Selected.png"
        Image
        {id: name; source: img_src ? img_src : img
            anchors.fill: parent}
        MouseArea
        {anchors.fill: parent
            onEntered:{name.source = "HDX_Caps_Enter_Selected.png"}
            onExited:{ name.source = abc.png"
            }}}}

Comment: My example also works when you have the button pressed. So, maybe I misunderstood? Also your example in the above comment contains some errors.